P0430 CEL with A/F Sensor: Sensor or catalytic converter? (Wide Range Sensor 1)
Normally compare Sensor 1 & 2 voltages BUT sensor 1 is A/F type and has steady voltage.
NOTE: Using Torque Pro, there is no Sensor 1 Voltage data available (or should I be looking for a Sensor 1 Wide Range Voltage?  which they may have in a different area of the LONG data list?)  They ONLY have Wide Range Current AND Wide Range Equivalence Ratio which are both steady values.  BUT should be moot since Wide Range
Both Sensor 2's (230K FlexFuel 3.0L V6 2011 Ford Escape) are not steady and oscillate with synced period, not unlike an upstream O2 sensor.  The bad bank B2S2 has greater peak-to-peak range than the good B1S2. So being "less steady" it is the bad cat?
Next Question:  Should I also replace B1 cat?  I'm thinking not because that one is much more difficult and also: I don't drive much and it may hang in there for another year or two.)
Other Question:  What would a bad B2S2 look like?  Do they lose their calibration?  Odds bad sensor?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
